# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition()

Tags: fatal-error, flat-catalog

I have enabled flat catalog in the magento admin. When i want to post image and hyperlink to website from facebook it cause fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::getProductsPosition() in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php on line 330

the website has 6000 products and without flat catalog enabled the product page load time is 8 second so i cannot afford to disable flat catalog.

Comment: what's the code that calls `getProductsPosition` in the first place. Normally this is called in actions that are not supposed to be called from the frontend. Check your custom modules.

Comment: when i search a product on the search tab, it fetches the product but when i click on it, it pops up the same error

Comment: which Magento version you are using ?

Comment: The version is 1.9.0.1